# GA User Explorer shows zero seconds session time

Tags: google-analytics

In the user explorer we are noticing for many users, there are 0s sessions followed by a consolidated session.

Our session time out in the application is 24 mins, with ajax polling in place after every 15 mins to avoid any timeouts, but as per GA observation ( attached as screenshot ), we don't see it as a session timeout as its during the same time frame.

We see that the same session is not getting consolidated.

Can this be a malicious user or bot which runs its scan?

It would be great if any pointers are provided as in what context this can happen and what should we review at our end to fix this.

Regards

[GA_0s_user_session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ltFX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Surely there is something that changes the source / medium / campaign and therefore interrupts the session and initializes another.

Those sessions where time equals 0 means that they are single page sessions. I believe there are redirects or or something that doesn't handle the referral well.